# How to validate public facing apis urls and responses against specifications

Tags: api, rest, validation

We have a project having public facing REST APIs.
We have documented standard practices so that developer can cross check the APIs, reviewers have to keep those in mind.
I was wondering if there is any tool where we can configure for set of rules, supply REST endpoints and it validates endpoints against the rules?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Postman , SOAP UI ,  swagger?